# Core Data - crashes with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

***Code is***:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
        return sections.count
    }

    return 0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections {
        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects + 3
    }

    return 3
}

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    print("controllerWillChangeContent")
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    print("controllerDidChangeContent")
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    print("didChangeObject: \(indexPath?.row), \(newIndexPath?.row)")
    var _indexPath, _newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
    if let path = indexPath {
        _indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: path.row + 3, inSection: path.section)
    }
    if let path = newIndexPath {
        _newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: path.row + 3, inSection: path.section)
    }

    switch type {
        case .Insert:
            print("insert: \(_indexPath?.row), \(_newIndexPath?.row), \(self.fetchedResultsController.sections?[0].numberOfObjects)")
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            break
        case .Update:
            print("update: \(_indexPath?.row), \(_newIndexPath?.row)")
            self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            break
        case .Delete:
            print("delete: \(_indexPath?.row), \(_newIndexPath?.row)")
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([_indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            break
        case .Move:
            print("move: \(_indexPath?.row), \(_newIndexPath?.row)")
            if _indexPath?.row != _newIndexPath?.row {
                self.tableView.moveRowAtIndexPath(_indexPath!, toIndexPath: _newIndexPath!)
            }
            break
    }
}
```

Each row has a button. The click event on that button triggers the update in `NSManagedObjectContext`:

```
chat?.managedObjectContext?.performBlockAndWait({
    let mutableData = chat?.data?.mutableCopy() as? NSMutableDictionary
    mutableData?.setObject(true, forKey: "isAnswered")
    chat?.data = mutableData?.copy() as? NSDictionary
    do {
        if chat?.managedObjectContext?.hasChanges == true {
            try chat?.managedObjectContext?.save()
        }
    } catch {
        print("Unable to save: \(error)")
    }
})
```

***Scenario 1:*** When there is any update in the last `NSManagedObject` in the list (there are 328 `NSManagedObject` + 3 `String`s), the logs are as follows:

```
controllerWillChangeContent
didChangeObject: Optional(328), nil
update: Optional(331), nil
didChangeObject: Optional(328), Optional(328)
insert: Optional(331), Optional(331), Optional(329)
controllerDidChangeContent

*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44.2.2/UITableView.m:1406

CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to insert row 332 into section 0, but there are only 332 rows in section 0 after the update with userInfo (null)
```

***Scenario 2:*** When there is any `update` in others rows except last one, the log is:

```
controllerWillChangeContent
didChangeObject: Optional(325), nil
update: Optional(328), nil
didChangeObject: Optional(325), Optional(325)
insert: Optional(328), Optional(328), Optional(329)
controllerDidChangeContent

*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44.2.2/UITableView.m:1623

CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (332) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (332), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (2 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)
```

**Problems:**

1. Why `NSFetchedResultsController` triggering `update` + `insert`, when there is only `update` in the object ?
2. The rows are not getting refreshed, what should I do ?, and
3. How can I resolve these warnings ?

Comment: Why did you add the optional bindings in `didChangeObject`? The method works perfectly without them. The potential `nil` values are never used in the appropriate modes. And use native Swift collection types. It's much easier and you get mutability for free.

Comment: Are you asking about function parameters, or the `NSIndexPath`s in the function ?

Comment: No I mean the `if let path =` expressions. Leave the method as it is in the Core Data template. And try to get rid of the optionals. For example `NSManagedObjectContext` is non-optional in the template.

Comment: Because `indexPath` and `newIndexPath` are optional, and I need to manipulate each of them (if not nil), to make it to point to `+ 3` row.

Comment: Is that the cause of problem(s), or it is just a syntax issue that is 'not related to the question' ?

Comment: Syntax issue, otherwise I would have written an answer. But I suspect that's also the problem.